# What's the best way to share a texture/image between two context with out context sharing?

Tags: opengl

What I want to do is to get the render result from one context, and do some further rendering in another context which do not shared with the previous one.

The only method I can come up with is that copy the render result from GPU memory to system memory using glReadPixels like APIs and use the copied data in another context.

Is there a better way to do this? I mean without copying the data from GPU memory to system memory and system to GPU again.

I am working with GLX under Linux.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: glX extension under linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to share them correctly. The closest I could find for GLX is the [GLX_NV_copy_image](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/copy_image.txt) extension. In the introduction, it says:

> The WGL and GLX versions allow copying between images in different contexts, even if those contexts are in different sharelists or even on different physical devices.

With this extension, you would use the `glXCopyImageSubDataNV()` function to copy from one context to the other. While this does not allow sharing, it might still be much faster than copying the data yourself.

As you can already tell from the name, this is a vendor specific extension. I don't know how widely supported it is, but you certainly shouldn't count on it being present on all systems.

Other window system bindings have mechanisms for sharing images even between processes. E.g. with EGL, which is used with OpenGL ES, EGLImage can be used for this purpose. But from browsing through the GLX spec and list of extensions, I couldn't spot anything similar there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this out since I'm just using Nvidia cards.

Comment: I cannot get this to work as you can't share direct contexts that I have found (i.e. using glXGetContextIDEXT to export a GLX XID and glXImportContextEXT to get the context back) on import, it will always return 0, because the contexts are direct.  Additionally, it seems impossible to build a surrogate indirect GLX Context.  Any diea how this could actually be done?

Answer (score 2):

If hacks are in order you could use CUDA or OpenCL for this. Works only on GPUs that support either CUDA or OpenCL though.

Comment: Is there no other way just using openGL?

Comment: @CurtisGuo: RetoKoradi pointed you to another method. However neither what I suggested nor GLX_NV_copy_image are strictly pure OpenGL solutions. OpenGL always operated in the context of a, well, OpenGL context. Anything that flings around data between different OpenGL contexts is ultimately not a core OpenGL function. Strictly speaking GLX is not part of OpenGL but X11.

Comment: Thanks for such detail explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There are also AMD extensions which might be of some relevance to this qeustion: [WGL_AMD_gpu_association](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/wgl_gpu_association.txt) and [GLX_AMD_gpu_association](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/glx_gpu_association.txt):

While this extension's focus is assigning GL context to specific GPUs and efficiently copying data between GPUs, it might also be useful for two contexts on the same GPU:

> To provide an accelerated path for blitting data from one context to another, the new blit function blitContextFramebufferAMD has been added.

These extensions and also some synchronization techniques for using them are covered in somewhat more detail in [this AMD whitepaper](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/GPU_Association_WhitePaper.pdf).