# Share rendered texture between Unity and Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, unity-game-engine

I have a 3D environment done in Unity which I wan't to have as an `Item` in Qt (QML). I've tried a few different paths, but none has proved to be efficient enough or I'm unable to get it to work.

My current working solution is to do the following each frame

1. In Unity, use `ReadPixels` of my `RenderTexture` (GPU) to get a regular `Texture` (RAM).
2. Encode to JPG and send bytearray through TCP socket.
3. In Qt, instantiate a `QImage` from the data and save it for later use.
4. In the render function of `QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer`, use `glTexImage2D` to render the image to my active texture.

Obviously this is not an optimal solution. This performs maybe 10 fps with a 128x64 texture size (for testing). My understanding is that the bottleneck is transferring data from gpu and back.

In my latest attempts I have tried to get the ID of the `RenderTexture` using `renderTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr()`. Then in Qt I'm trying to get the pixel data through `glGetTexImage`, but I keep getting 0's in the data. When later using `glDrawPixels`, the Qt application crashes.

So my question now is, do anyone know if it's possible to share the texture between processes and if so, how?

Comment: So ultimately you want to display your Unity render in a Qt application? If so, why not go the direct "embed" round by making use of the `-parentHWND` command line argument? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

Comment: `Obviously this is not an optimal solution` - it is the furthest from optimal. As soon as you VRAM to RAM to VRAM again you are killing it. The extra stuff is on top of that. The question here really is "sharing a texture between different processes". Also it may be easier to integrate the two in the same application.

Comment: @Bart yes that's a good suggestion and it actually works really well. However, it hijacks the whole window and I can't find a way of displaying stuff on top of the unity rendering. If you know a way to do that, I'm all ears. One problem though is that you wouldn't be able to resize or do anything with the texture, which I would like to do in the long run.

Comment: @ddriver: Sadly I can't integrate them in to the same application. I made a search for "sharing a texture between different processes" and I get some relevant hits. However, one is [old](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/168418-Sharing-Texture-amongst-different-Process) and gives no solution and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936567/whats-the-best-way-to-share-a-texture-image-between-two-context-with-out-contex) might work but uses vendor specific code.

Comment: The solution will definitely be vendor specific. There is no going around that. It is not a standard thing to do.